# Spreadsheet:: ParseExcel in PERL query

Tags: excel, perl, spreadsheet, parseexcel

I am writing a PERL code to pick values from specific rows of a particular excel sheet. I am using the Spreadsheet::ParseExcel module for this purpose. I have written this code as of now

> ```
> use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::FmtDefault;
> use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
>
>       my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
>
>         #my $name = <STDIN>;
>   die "You must provide a filename to $0 to be parsed as an Excel file" unless @ARGV;
>       my $workbook = $parser->parse($ARGV[0]);
>   my @values;
>       if ( !defined $workbook ) {
>         die $parser->error(), ".\n";
>     }
>
>       for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
>
>         my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
>         my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();
>
>         for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
>           for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
>
>                 my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
>                 next unless $cell;
>                 $cell->value();
>           my $cell_type = $cell->{Type};
>                 if ($cell_type =~/Numeric/)
>               {
>                 push @values, $cell->unformatted();
>       }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

I am able to pick all the numeric values in a particular excel sheet with this particular code, but I would like to tweak the code so that it could pick up numeric values in specific columns as per the users needs (eg: all the numeric values in row B or row C). How do I go about tweaking my code to make that possible or are there simpler modules available in which the range (eg B2 - B22) can be specified. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you need B column values from 2nd row to 22nd row or in generic to get values froma particular column ?

Comment: @Praveen Generic code to get values from a particular column that the user needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with the below perl code. Excel sheet row and column values start with (0,0). So accordingly enter your column and row numbers repectively to get your desired output.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('C:\Users\Perl\test1.xls');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
 die $parser->error(), ".\n";
     }
my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet(0);
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

COLUMNS: print "Select the column number required from Excel\n";
my $column = <STDIN>;
chomp($column);
unless ($column =~/[0-9]+/){
print "Bummer!! Please Enter a number\n";
goto COLUMNS;
}

if($column gt $col_max){
     print "No such columns defined in the Excel";
     goto END;
      }

ROWS:print "Select number of rows required from column $column:\n";
my $rows = <STDIN>;
chomp($rows);
my $count = $rows+1;
unless ($rows =~/[0-9]+/){
print "Bummer!! Please Enter a number\n";
goto ROWS;
}

  ROW_LABEL: if($rows le $row_max)
    {  
    print "\nThe $count row values from column $column are:\n"; 
    for my $row ( $row_min .. $rows ) {

        my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $column );
        next unless $cell;
        my $result = $cell->value();        
        print $result . "\n";
          }
       }
    else
     {   
      $rows = $row_max;
      goto ROW_LABEL ;
         }       
 END:
```